# При первом запуске приложения загрузка происходит долго

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!

Я использую приложение с БД, когда запускаю приложение после установки, порядка 15-20 секунд лишь белый экран и `statusbar`. Я так понимаю что это по причине того, что бд выгружается? При повтором запуске грузит быстро. Я в `asynctask` прописал анимацию с задержкой в 5 секунд, но и сама анимация начинается только после разгрузки(как я думаю) БД, я хочу установить анимацию, и чтобы она продолжалась до тех пор, пока БД выгружается, где именно мне вызывать анимацию? Или причина такой задержки при первом запуске в чем-то другом?
ps.. размер файла базы данных `411кб`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    UpdateTask myUpdateTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

        myUpdateTask = new UpdateTask();
        myUpdateTask.execute();
    }

    private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            TextView mTextAnim = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_anim);
            ImageView mImgAnim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_anim);
            TextView mTextAnim2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_anim2);

            Animation myAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.my_scale);

            mTextAnim.startAnimation(myAnimation);
            mImgAnim.startAnimation(myAnimation);
            mTextAnim2.startAnimation(myAnimation);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

Comment: покажите код! если используете AsyncTask нужно стартовать анимацию закрузки в onPreExecute , а останавливать в onPostExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это происходит в debug режиме, то ничего страшного - просто инициализируются DEX-файлы для работы Instant Run.
При сборке подписанного приложения такого не будет.

Также, можно отключить быстрый запуск Instant Run.  File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> убрать флаг "Enable Instant Run".

Совсем олдскульный вариант - использовать студию 1.5.2 http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-5-2 , там ещё не было этой фичи.

Comment: Да, именно debug режим.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример использования `ProgressDialog` с `AsyncTask`

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private MyActivity activity;

        public ProgressTask(MyActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        private Context context;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {             
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
            //тут ваш код с запросами к БД
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: У меня нет проблем с реализацией `asynctask`, однако, как я говорил и ранее, я вызываю в нем анимацию чтобы она длилась все то время, пока не выгрузится БД, я реализовал `asynctask` в `MainActivity`, и он срабатывает, но только после того, как 15-20 секунд висит белый экран со `statusbar`'ом. А при последующих запусках сразу начинается запуск анимации

Comment: покажите ваш код

Comment: Обновил, можете посмотреть

Comment: Андрей Г., дал ответ, а приведенный вами фрагмент кода я заменю на свой.